# How to find the text field data has \n?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

How to find the text field data has \n  in mysql?

for ex :

field :

```
address  :asfalghaln asdgl sdnslbvaslcbn 

address2 : adsadas
phone :2323
```

How to find the address has \n or not ? in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a [string function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to verify the presence of single characters:

```
SELECT FROM YourTable WHERE LOCATE("\n", textColumn) != 0;
```

This won't work, if the first character is a newline, though, so you might want to check that too:

```
SELECT FROM YourTable WHERE LEFT(textColumn, 1) != "\n" AND LOCATE("\n", textColumn) != 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is ASCII character 10.  You can get the A ASCII char from the `char` function in mysql.

```
SELECT char(10)
```

Instr will give you the position in the string of the \n character

```
SELECT INSTR('my new
line', char(10));
```

A value of > 0 will indicate the \n is present (and where it is) a 0 value indicates there is no \n.

Comment: INSTR is almost the same as LOCATE (arguments are reversed), and you still have the problem with the first character.